# Angular Material Autocomplete - How to allow user to add item not in suggested list?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I'm trying to implement the autocomplete component from Angular Material:

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview

It works well for letting the user select a particular item from the suggested list but I also want to allow the user to add items not in the list.

So lets say the suggested list has the following items:

```
Cats
Birds
Dogs
```

And the user starts typing `"Do"` and the autocomplete shows `"Dogs"` as the suggested option (because I'm also filtering the list based on what they type). But then the user continues typing `"Dolls"` and now nothing is displayed in the autocomplete suggestions. Then the user hits enter and it gets added to the list.

Current behavior is that if what the user typed doesn't exist in the list then they are unable to add the item.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you add an enter key listener to the input field, you can process the entered value and add it to the options if it doesn't exist. You can also dynamically add whatever the user enters to the list of filtered options as an "add new item" option, or add an "add" icon to the field (e.g. as a matSuffix). Or you can do all three:

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzf9dw-c7az71)

HTML

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Item" aria-label="Item" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="itemCtrl" (keyup.enter)="addOption()">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="optionSelected($event.option)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredItems | async" [value]="item">
        <span>{{ item }}</span>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
    <button *ngIf="showAddButton && itemCtrl.value" matSuffix mat-button mat-icon-button (click)="addOption()"><mat-icon matTooltip='Add "{{itemCtrl.value}}"'>add</mat-icon></button>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

TS

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators/startWith';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';

/**
 * @title Autocomplete with add new item option
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-overview-example.css']
})
export class AutocompleteOverviewExample {
  itemCtrl: FormControl;
  filteredItems: Observable<any[]>;
  showAddButton: boolean = false;

  prompt = 'Press <enter> to add "';

  items: string[] = [
    'Cats',
    'Birds',
    'Dogs'
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.itemCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.filteredItems = this.itemCtrl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(item => item ? this.filterItems(item) : this.items.slice())
      );
  }

  filterItems(name: string) {
    let results = this.items.filter(item =>
      item.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);

    this.showAddButton = results.length === 0;
    if (this.showAddButton) {
      results = [this.prompt + name + '"'];
    }

    return results;
  }

  optionSelected(option) {
    if (option.value.indexOf(this.prompt) === 0) {
      this.addOption();
    }
  }

  addOption() {
    let option = this.removePromptFromOption(this.itemCtrl.value);
    if (!this.items.some(entry => entry === option)) {
      const index = this.items.push(option) - 1;
      this.itemCtrl.setValue(this.items[index]);
    }
  }

  removePromptFromOption(option) {
    if (option.startsWith(this.prompt)) {
      option = option.substring(this.prompt.length, option.length -1);
    }
    return option;
  }
}
```

Comment: Notably, this was working for me for a while (I thought), but I've recently ran into some issues on the "click" method (works fine with "enter"). It seems the optionSelected method gets stuck in the scope of the mat-autocomplete component itself. So, none of the custom component methods can be accessed via this, and are not available. Even though they are necessary for updating the upstream list of objects that the mat-autcomplete depends on. Angular 16.0.0 and Material 16.0.0 on latest Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

It's weird that the user can *add* an item in the *suggested* list. The list is *suggested* to the user by someone who knows what to suggest. But anyway...

The user can type anything in the field and ignore the suggestions. By ignoring the suggested *Dogs* and typing *Dolls*, user can press an "Add" button which will add whatever is typed in (*Dolls*) to the `options` array.

For example, you can do it by listening to the submit event on the form:

```
(ngSubmit)="options.push(myControl.value); myControl.reset()"
```

Here's the [**complete demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b69ykm?file=app/autocomplete-simple-example.html) as well.

Comment: Plenty of valid scenarios for the requested behavior.  For example a Tagging system, you want autocomplete for tags already in the system, but don't want to restrict to only those tags.  If a user enters a new tag then add it to the list of "existing tags".

Comment: Also adding logic directly on the page works - I can't imagine this as a best practice.  You should really add a function to the component.ts file and call it from the (ngSubmit).